# What indicators might point to a successful research stay?

Tags: research-process, visiting, student-exchange

I will be going to Norway in January for a 3-month predoc research stay. I would like to hear your opinion on what aspects you would consider successful in a research stay.

Making contacts, advancing research, publishing articles could be some indicators, what others would you add?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "how should I invest my energy?" ?

Comment: @paul garrett My question is rather aimed at what characteristics a successful stay should ideally have in your opinion (i.e. on what criteria would you base the success of a research stay)?

Comment: You may be "over-thinking" this opportunity. There is no need, and little served, I think, by trying to measure it... It is an opportunity, not a test.

Comment: Unless your field is radically different than mine, publishing anything in three months is definitely not an indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Even going somewhere for three months and not doing anything besides catching up with your own work left behind, while not talking nor making useful contacts with anyone there would be a succesful research stay.

Even going there, not doing anything for three months besides saving money from the scolarship can be considered a success (research&academia will unfortunately provide you ample occasions of unpaid spells, so saving money **is** a success indicator because you will do science on your own savings).

Research is failure. Think what is the greatest failure you can achieve in three months, then pursue the opposite in your pre-doc norwegian stay.